# subsubsection without subsection but restart numbers in next section

Tags: sectioning, numbering

Well I have a problem that look like this

> 1.First section
>    1.first subsubsection
>    2.second subsubsection
>    2.Second section
>    3.third subsubsection

how do i fix like

> 1.First section
>    1.first subsubsection
>    2.second subsubsection
>    2.Second section
>    1.another first subsubsection

this?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you want a subsubsection without a subsection???

If it is just a one-off then `\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}` will reset it, if it is a general feature then (a) something is very wrong: you should not need to do this and (b) you can do

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{subsubsection}{section}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I fixed some typos...